# Emailing names in a contacts list using Designer

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email

I have a SharePoint list with accounts, names, and email addresses. 
This list is updated regularly by various people.

What I want to do is set up a workflow that will send an email to all the email addresses in the list on a set date each month, preferably as one email.

I don't want to go down the route of creating a separate distribution address in Exchange that also needs to be managed as this just adds additional work which could lead to mismatch in information.

Platform is SharePoint 2013 but with 2010 SharePoint Designer workflows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list workflow in SharePoint Designer that is attached to your Contacts List.
2. Type in "Email" to get the email action
3. in the "To" field, do a "Workflow Lookup for a user"
4. Select "Current Item" in the "Data Source" drop-down
5. Select "Email Address" in the "Field From Source" drop-down

[image: Email Contacts]

6. Compose your email
7. Save and publish your workflow

Now you need a way to start the workflow on each of the contacts, on a schedule.

This can be done with PowerShell, and Task Scheduler (on the SharePoint server):

```
$SiteURL = "YOUR SITE URL"
$ContactsList = "YOUR CONTACT LIST NAME"
$WorkflowName = "NAME OF YOUR EMAIL WORKFLOW"
$Region = "en-US" # Change if needed
#####################################
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $SiteURL
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager
$list = $web.Lists[$ContactsList]
$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName($WorkflowName,$Region)
$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$items = $list.Items
foreach($item in $items)
{
    $wfs = $manager.GetItemWorkflows($item)
    foreach ($wf in $wfs)
    {
        $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true)
    }
}
$manager.Dispose()
$web.Dispose()
```

Then all you need to do is run the above script on a schedule, in Task Scheduler.

If you add more people to the contacts list in the future, they will also get the email when the workflow is triggered.

Comment: Thanks Nulldata, unfortunately, I dont have access tot he server, only front end access to the site.

Comment: Can you ask the sharepoint admin to help with the last step?